# ImageJ API: How to insert one image to another image

Tags: java, image, image-processing, copy, imagej

I am using ImageJ for image processing in my spring boot app.
Two basic functionalities which I need:
1. Drawing text
2. Pasting image into another image using specific credentials

First of all my text seems to be little blurry no matter which font/size. Am I missing something?

```
ImagePlus imagePlus = new ImagePlus();
imagePlus.setImage(myImage);
ImageProcessor ip = imagePlus.getProcessor();
ip.setFont(new Font("Roboto", 1, 25));
ip.drawString("Example text", 50, 100);
```

What is more I have problem with second part of it - no idea how to achieve this.
After some research I've found information that I need to create ROI of first image then copy it to second image. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Maybe someone can provide example code for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you confirm that anti-aliasing is on for the text?  You should also consider checking the difference between the font size and how you render the image; as far as I know the ImageJ fonts are in pixels, so if you're exporting images and shrinking them, this may the cause of the blurriness.

Comment: For the second point, see if you can manage to copy the image over as you intend to with the macro recorder on.  If you can manage it by hand, the recorder should be sufficient to give you the remaining commands you need.